# How to order by a column with Visualization Query API

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

I have a query to order column in google sheets in ascending order and it works fine. The default behavior of sort is to put null values at the top before sorting the other data. Is there any way to make null values go to the bottom (i.e after all other records)?

Comment: Try `order by A desc`

Comment: This won't achieve the desired result because the items would be in descending order. I want the records to be in ascending  order but with the null values sent to the bottom.

Comment: You could use `Where A is null` and use the resulting array  and combine it with a `;` to another query `Where A is not null order A asc`